# Decision Tree - How does decision tree select rules on each node

Tags: machine-learning, classification, data-science, decision-tree

I am learning decision tree algorithm in machine learning

What I could understand from tutorials is that at each node decision tree calculate Information gain and based on that it determines the best attribute for the node.

But what I am not able to get is that how does it define the best rule for each node.

Let say if age is the best attribute for a particular node. In that case if decision tree select rule age > 50 then my question is how it came to this rule ?

And also please explain the below :

Decision tree divides the data in homogeneous subsets at each level.

Comment: A suggest that your review a good tutorial on decision trees, [such as this one](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/04/complete-tutorial-tree-based-modeling-scratch-in-python/#three).

Answer (score 4):

Basically, there are two main steps. First, there is feature selection which is the best candidate for the next split (use e.g. Gini Index or Entropy). Second, you compute Information gain before and after a split and you want to have the gain maximal (you can use a greedy approach).

There is a nice series of article about decision trees which also discuss the advantages and limitations, [Decision Trees. Decoded](https://medium.com/data-science-group-iitr/decision-trees-decoded-c70b4f7ff542).

Answer (score 3):

At each node, the split function chooses the feature and the value for that feature (at which to split the records), which minimises the cost for both subsets of records. So, it chooses both feature and value simultaneuously. The cost function depends on the setting, classification or regression, but could for example be the entropy, note here that minimising entropy is equivalent to maximising the information gain (as you describe in your question).

More intuitively, the goal is to create subsets of records that are purest, that is each subset contains as many samples as possible, belonging to just one class. Another way to say this is that the subsets should be as *homogeneous* or as pure as possible.

For more details, any introductory text book on machine learning is a good starting point here, see e.g. [Introduction to Statistical Learning](https://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/ISLR%20First%20Printing.pdf) by Tibshirani and Hastie et al.

Comment: So , that means it iterates over all possible values of a particular attribute to find the best rule ? and it goes for all the nodes and attibutes ?

Comment: The set of threshold values for splitting the data can be obtained by taking the unique observed (rather than all possible) values for each feature.

Answer (score 1):

First of all Jirka and mloning are perfectly clear answers, you should definitely take a look at what they suggest.

I think your question comes from a little confusion regarding how decision trees work (a perfectly natural one, by the way !). The best split is selected as the one that minimizes an impurity function, and this impurity function does not depend on the nature of the covariates. It only depends on how a given split distributes the observations of the parent node in the child nodes. That is for the "Decision tree divides the data in homogeneous subsets at each level." part of your question.
And YES, it iterates over all possible different splits.

If you want some visualisation of that, here is a video explaining that: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J0fpXEIAzwk&t=653s

The answer to your specific question is treated at 7:45.

In addition regarding the "Decision tree divides the data in homogeneous subsets at each level." part of your question: It is generally true but also depends on the nature of the target variable though. Gini Index and entropy are great for classification and divide the data to maximize homogeneity. Other functions such as the simple MSE should be used for regression and also divides the data to maximize homogeneity.
But more complex splitting procedures can be required for survival problems for instance, where the split selected is rather the one that maximizes the "between node heterogeneity" rather than the "within node homogeneity". Even if that is subtle, that is not mathematically equivalent.